# Search & Update properties of an object nested in a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, javascript-objects

Say I have an array of nested objects like

```
let vendors = [
    {
        v_id: 'red',
        count: 2,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'blue',
        count: 3,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'green',
        count: 1,
    },
];
```

And another object "foo" with many properties, one of which is "v_id".
Based on the value of foo.v_id, I want to either update the counts in the "vendors" array or add a new object to "vendors".

If foo.v_id matches one of those in the "vendors" array, the corresponding count increases by 1.

Example:

```
let foo = {
    user_type: 'Other',
    v_id: 'blue'
};
```

Then "vendors" would become:

```
[
    {
        v_id: 'red',
        count: 2,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'blue',
        count: 4,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'green',
        count: 1,
    },
];
```

Else, if there is no match of v_id, a new object is added to the "vendors" array with the corresponding v_id & count = 1.

Example:

```
let foo = {
    user_type: 'client',
    v_id: 'yellow',
};
```

Then "vendors" would become:

```
[
    {
        v_id: 'red',
        count: 2,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'blue',
        count: 3,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'green',
        count: 1,
    },
    {
        v_id: 'yellow',
        count: 1,
    },
];
```

How can I efficiently & elegantly do this in Javascript? I know I can use `.filter()` to get the specific object in "vendors" that has to be updated but how would I update the "vendors" array itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the object in the array by `v_id`. If the object is in the array, increment `count`. If not push a new object:

```js
const vendors = [{"v_id":"red","count":2},{"v_id":"blue","count":3},{"v_id":"green","count":1}];
const foo1 = { user_type: 'Other', v_id: 'blue' };
const foo2 = { user_type: 'client', v_id: 'yellow' };

const addUpdate = (arr, obj) => {
  const current = arr.find((o) => o.v_id === obj.v_id);
  
  if(current) current.count += 1;
  else arr.push({
    v_id: obj.v_id,
    count: 1
  });
};

addUpdate(vendors, foo1);
addUpdate(vendors, foo2);

console.log(vendors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function upsert(arr, obj){
  const index = arr.findIndex(item => item.v_id === obj.v_id);
  index === -1 ? arr.push({v_id: obj.v_id, count: 1}) : arr[index].count++
}

let vendors = [{v_id: 'red',count: 2}, {v_id: 'blue',count: 3}, {v_id: 'green',count: 1}];
let foo1 = {user_type: 'Other', v_id: 'blue'};
let foo2 = {user_type: 'client', v_id: 'yellow'};

upsert(vendors, foo1);
upsert(vendors, foo2);

console.log(vendors);
```